# Relation between rank and null space of transpose

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra, algebra-precalculus

I have to find the relation between rank(A) and nullity(A^T)
I know the rank nullity theorem but confused in transpose. For example if A has dimension 5×9 and rank(A)=5 what is nullity(A^T)

Comment: For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: Do you know that $A$ and $A^T$ have the same rank? Do you know the rank-nullity theorem?

Comment: I knew rank nullity theorem. Rank + Nullity = dimension of domain

Comment: That’s right. What does that mean for a matrix? What does that mean for $A^T$?